# Why does (0 && 1 == 0) not evaluate to true?

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, logical-operators, equals-operator

In my `if` statement, the first condition for `&&` is `0` (false), so the expression `0 && (a++)` is equal to `0`, right? Then `0==0` it should be true. Why am I getting `else` here? Please explain!

```
int a=0;
if(0 && (a++)==0)
{
    printf("Inside if");
}
else
{
    printf("Else");
}
printf("%i",a);
```

Comment: First, `a++` evaluates to 0, and increments `a` later. But even if it evaluated to a non-zero value, `==` binds more strongly than `&&` (has higher precedence), so your expression is equivalent to `0 && ((a++) == 0)`, which is false regardless of what `(a++) == 0` evaluates to.

Comment: The precedence of `==` is higher than `&&`. Add parentheses `(0 && (a++))==0`

Comment: Now that you have your answer, I recommend reviewing your question. Do you see where your logic failed you? (In one respect, it is an interesting question because your deductions are literally valid, yet they end up being not applicable.)

Comment: `if(0 && (a++)==0)` is horrible code and should fail any code review.  Code that makes you go look up precedence tables is flat-out wrong.  You ***WILL*** botch writing such code eventually, even if you think you have perfect memory (hint: ***no one*** does...).  A real simple rule-of-thumb:  if it's not painfully obvious what a line of code does, it's ***wrong***.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `==` operator has a higher priority than the `&&` operator, so this line:

```
if(0 && (a++)==0)
```

is treated like this:

```
if(  0 && ((a++)==0) )
```

So the whole expression under the `if` is false, and `a++` is not even evaluated due to short circuitry of the `&&` operator.

You can read about [Operator Precedence and Associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) on cppreference.com.

When in doubt, you should use parenthesis to express your intention clearly. In this case, it should be:

```
if( (0 && (a++)) == 0  )
```

Though, it does not make any sense, as it always evaluates to `true` and `a++` is not incremented here, either.

Comment: Note that even in revised version, a++ will never execute.

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned, the precedence of `==` is higher than precedence of `&&`, so the statement is resolved into

```
if( 0 && ((a++)==0))
```

However, still even if you add the correct order of brackets, `a++` returns the original value of `a`, which is `0`, but the `a` is incremented. If you want to return the updated value of `a`, you should write `++a`

```
if( ((++a) && 0) == 0  )
```

Answer (score -1):

Although the question seems easy it's very error-prone.
We need to know the precedence of various operators involved in this.

```
1. postfix (++)
2. ==
3. Logical AND (&&)
```

the final expression can be seen as: `if ( (0 && (a++)) == 0 )`
which is true. Hence statement under if is evaluated to be true.

Comment: Except that the question asks about `if (0 && a++ == 0)`, which is equivalent to `if (0 && (a++ == 0))`, not to `if ( (0 && a++) == 0 )` (as explained in the other answers)...

Comment: The question is **why the condition is false**. You seem to answer a different question.